# Algorithm to locate unbalanced parentheses in a string

Tags: algorithm, parsing

PostScript/PDF string literals are surrounded by parentheses, and are allowed to contain unescaped parentheses *as long as the parentheses are fully balanced*.  So for instance

```
( () )  % valid string constant
( ( )   % invalid string constant, the inner ( should be escaped
```

I know an algorithm to tell me if there *are* any unbalanced parentheses in a string; what I'm looking for is an algorithm that will *locate* a minimal set of parentheses that are unbalanced, so that I can then stick backslashes in front of them to make the whole a valid string literal. More examples:

```
(     ⟶   \(
()    ⟶   ()
(()   ⟶   \(() or (\()
())   ⟶   ()\) or (\))
()(   ⟶   ()\(
```

Comment: Any preferred language for code examples?

Comment: How large are your input strings?

Comment: The project this is for is currently in Python; second preference is C-family.  If you happen to have something to hand in some other language I can probably deal, though (unless it's a deliberately write-only language).

Comment: The strings are likely to be no more than a few hundred bytes long, I think.

Comment: You might find something useful in compiler error recovery/correction. It's a difficult problem though.

Answer (score 3):

A modification of the standard stack based algorithm to detect imbalanced parenthesis should work for you. Here's some pseudo code:

```
void find_unbalaned_indices(string input)
{
    // initialize 'stack' containing of ints representing index at
    // which a lparen ( was seen

    stack<int index> = NIL          

    for (i=0 to input.size())
    {
        // Lparen. push into the stack
        if (input[i] == '(')
        {
            // saw ( at index=i
            stack.push(i);
        }
        else if (input[i] == ')')
        {
           out = stack.pop();
           if (out == NIL)
           {
               // stack was empty. Imbalanced RParen.
               // index=i needs to be escaped
               ... 
           }  
           // otherwise, this rparen has a balanced lparen.
           // nothing to do.
        }
    }

    // check if we have any imbalanced lparens
    while (stack.size() != 0)
    {
        out = stack.pop();
        // out is imbalanced
        // index = out.index needs to be escaped.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you highlight a specific case where this would fail? My idea was that I wouldn't be able to do any faster than O(N) (lenght of string). I have to read the chars atleast once.

Comment: This looks good to me. It will escape the nearest parenthesis needed to keep things balanced, which is as good a choice as any.

Comment: @Sanjit: the problem is no that the algorithm "fail" or that it is slow, the problem is that error recovery is difficult because it means trying to presume of the user's intent, which your algorithm does not attempt to. Think of a "real" case, instead of simply focusing on a string of parentheses. `mumbling about something (for example considering xx or yy (especially for case foo)`. Here your algorithm suggests escaping the first `(`, while the "obvious" solution to a human reader is to actually *add* a r-parenthesis at the end.

Comment: @Matthieu: This is a well-specified optimisation problem, all we're looking to do is compress as effectively as possible by omitting as many backslashes as possible.  As I understand the question, it isn't important whether the resulting string is "easy to read".  I believe marcog meant that Sanjit's strategy would sometimes yield non-minimal results (which BTW I think is an incorrect claim, though I can't prove it).

Comment: @j_random_hacker: given marcog previous comment on error recovery I do think he meant something about error recovery with "work so well" rather than optimization. I also think that Sanjit's strategy is excellent for purely balancing the parentheses without any care for the actual meaning, I need to think a bit about non-minimal results as I can't seem to be able to produce an example off the top of my head.

Comment: j_random_hacker is correct, I only want a solution that adds the minimum number of backslashes.  In the context of the larger problem, it would be incorrect to add parentheses (that would change the contents of the string constant).  I'm trying to see if I can either prove correct or break Sanjit's algorithm now.

Answer (score 0):

```
def escape(s):
    return ''.join(r(')(', r('()', s)))

def r(parens, chars):
    return reversed(list(escape_oneway(parens, chars)))

def escape_oneway(parens, chars):
    """Given a sequence of characters (possibly already escaped),
    escape those close-parens without a matching open-paren."""
    depth = 0
    for x in chars:
        if x == parens[0]:
            depth += 1
        if x == parens[1]:
            if depth == 0:
                yield '\\' + x
                continue
            else:
                depth -= 1
        yield x
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I don't feel that I understand it.  Can you explain the logic and make an argument (I don't need a formal proof) that it adds the minimal number of backslashes?

Comment: A ')' must be escaped iff there are no matching '('s to its left. escape_oneway() expresses that pretty directly. By symmetry, a '(' must be escaped iff there are no matching ')'s to its right. We reduce this to the first case by reversing the string and swapping the checks for '(' and ')'. There's a final reverse to undo that reversal. I convinced myself at the time that the second-pass escaping didn't affect any of the decisions made in the first pass, but I'm blanking on why and I need to run out now. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: This might well work correctly, but I think there's a hole in your reasoning: What is a "matching" '(' exactly?  It's possible that there is more than one '(' that *could* match a given ')', so you need to identify which one I think.  In case by "matching '('" you mean "'(' that *could* match", your initial statement's not correct -- witness `())`.  Exactly one of the ')'s must be escaped, and either works just as well.