# C# Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

Need a regular expression to match `{` and `}`.

Here is my requirement.

If the input is like

```
avsg{sdhsd{jh{ashdhas}hdasjhd}
```

...the output should be

```
avsgsdhsdjh{ashdhas}hdasjhd
```

I have to trim all the occurrences of `{` and `}` except if there is a matching `}` for a `{`.

EDIT -- some further examples:

Nested brackets are not allowed. We allow '{' and '}' that too only once and we remove all the brackets. Giving some more examples.

1). IN:afhad{adfh}jsdfhd OUT: afhad{adfh}jsdfhd

2). IN:afhad{a{dfh}jsdfhd OUT: afhada{dfh}jsdfhd

3). IN:afh{ad{adfh}jsdf}hd OUT:afhad{adfh}jsdfhd

4). IN:afhad{adfhjsdfhd OUT:afhadadfhjsdfhd

Comment: Did you mean a matching '{' for a '}'? Anyhow, the example doesn't make much sense in either way.

Comment: If the brackets are unbalanced how are you determining which one to remove? eg "{a{bc}" could be "{abc}" or "a{bc}". You need to specify this more clearly. And also I suspect this is one of those things that you can't do with regular expressions but I might be wrong.

Comment: Oh, your example implies that nested brackets are not allowed either. is that correct? If so it might be doable with regular expressions...

Comment: Nested brackets are not allowed. We allow '{' and '}' that too only once and we remove all the brackets.  Giving some more examples. 1). IN:afhad{adfh}jsdfhd OUT: afhad{adfh}jsdfhd 2). IN:afhad{a{dfh}jsdfhd OUT: afhada{dfh}jsdfhd 3). IN:afh{ad{adfh}jsdf}hd OUT:afhad{adfh}jsdfhd 4). IN:afhad{adfhjsdfhd OUT:afhadadfhjsdfhd

Comment: Hm, interesting question generally .. I wonder how code formatters work out where missing brackets are. Do they find the most-nested pair of brackets first, then work back out? Does that assume that the most-nested pair is actually right?

Comment: @Naresh: You should be able to edit your question to add in the extra requirements and examples. This makes them easier to see and find (and read) than in comments.

Comment: Ah, good old SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588695/algorithm-to-locate-unbalanced-parentheses-in-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"([^{}]*(?:\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*)(?:[{}]|$)", "$1");
```

`[^{}]*` matches zero or more of any characters except `{` or `}`.

`\{[^{}]*\}` matches an opening brace followed by a closing brace, with any number of any characters except braces between them.

All together, `([^{}]*(?:\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*)` matches zero or more non-braces or matched pairs of braces and captures them in group #1, and then `(?:[{}]|$)` matches the next unpaired brace or the end of the input.  Replacing the match with `$1` (the contents of group #1) effectively deletes the unpaired brace.

Comment: Oops!  I had to add `|$` to let it match the end of the string.  Without that, it would backtrack to match a brace every time, even if it was part of a matched pair.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string s = @"avsg{sdhsd{jh{ashdhas}hdasjhd}";

        string newS = Regex.Replace(s, @"^(.*)(\{.*?\})(.*)$", m =>
                m.Groups[1].Value.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "") +
                m.Groups[2].Value +
                m.Groups[3].Value.Replace("{","").Replace("}", "")
        );
```

Comment: Nice. I was trying to think of complciated regex with lookaheads and all that kind of thing whereas this very neatly gets the least nested thing. I'm not sure how it behaves (or should behave) if the input is "a{bc}de{fg}hi"...

Comment: Hello Petar, it's not working fine for the strings which have only '{'. For the string fjdgjdgf{asdjklfnsdfsf it is giving the output fjdgjdgf{asdjklfnsdfsf only. But in the expected output we have to remove the '{' or '}' if there is no matching bracket.

Comment: Does that just meet the requirement of this specific string, or this specific combination of parentheses?

Comment: For the input a{bc}de{fg}hi the output should be a{bc}de{fg}hi